# TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe' or 'expect'

Tags: angular, angular7

I generated a new project through Angular 7.2.1 when I open **app.e2e-spec.ts** I see `TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'` error. When I clicked on suggestion **Import describe from module "jasmine"** I see different error **TS2305: Module "/Users/pjadda/IdeaProjects/CyberJobs/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index"' has no exported member 'describe'.**
Not sure what's wrong here. This is new project generated through Angular CLI.

**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
import {AppPage} from './app.po';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to cyber-jobs!');
  });
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "cyber-jobs": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../../target/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cyber-jobs:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cyber-jobs:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cyber-jobs:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cyber-jobs-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "cyber-jobs:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "cyber-jobs:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "cyber-jobs"
}
```

Comment: What TypeScript and @types/jasmine version do you use?

Comment: @Jadda Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @Abhidev After updating to latest Angular, the issue was resolved

Comment: I'm on angular 8

Comment: Remove `node_modules` directory and do fresh `npm install`. If that doesn't solve your issue, delete whole project folder and download from git repository (Github, BitBucket etc.) and run `npm install`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have this dependency installed and import in any of your test file

```
import '@types/jest';
```

and add 'jest' to the types array in `tsconfig.json`